# Starting a service at a specific time every day

Tags: java, android, service, alarmmanager

i made a calendar to show toast in specific time every day at 8:00 pm
but the app show start the service and show the toast in different time.
like

```
8:00 pm
8:23 pm
8:30 pm
8:32 pm
8:50 pm
```

and doesn't stop showing the toast

what is the wrong?

this is my Mainactivity.java code

```
   Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

    setAlarm();

}

private void setAlarm() {
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    /* Set the alarm to start at 8.00 PM */
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    //Add a day if alarm is set for before current time, so the alarm is triggered the next day

    if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }

    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(1, TimeUnit.DAYS), pendingIntent);              

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [setRepeating](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

> Note: as of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.

**EDIT**
You alarm being inexact, it means that the system will not wake up in the exact time you set 00:800 to fulfill your request, instead it will group some actions that needs to be done, somewhere around the time you set, and fire them all together to save battery of the phone, and do prevent the phone from being awake every couple of seconds separately.

You can replace your call to non repeating call using `AlarmManager.set()` and handling repetition yourself, as in each alarm firing schedules the next one.

Or if your alarm firing is not time critical (it doesn't not have to be very exact), you can leave it as it is.

Comment: my api level is 23. can u edit my Mainactivity.java to understand u please

Comment: The quote above says that API 19 and above (that includes 23) will set your repeating alarm as inexact.  I'll update answer with little more explanation

Answer (score 0):

To have a precise alarm instead of using setRepeating use setAndAllowWhileIdle 
otherwise, if you are not in need of precise timing I would recommend you to use firebase job dispatcher to schedule your job https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android